# Am I allowed to print individual sheets or full Seforim from copyright Seforim found online?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, gezel-stealing, issur-vheter

"if someone posted a copyrighted book accessible online, what does halacha say about printing it? I'm worried about Gezeilah on the one hand, but perhaps since there is no loss to the owner it doesn't fall under this category".

Comment: The secular legal question is out of scope for this site. For the halachic question: what is your concern that brings you to ask this question?

Comment: @magicker72 Thank you for responding. Is it Gezeilah since many of the Seforim are likely copyright? Or perhaps since there is no loss to the owner it doesn't fall under this category. Or any other issues/Heteirim that I can't think of.

Comment: You're better off phrasing your question more generally: "if someone posted a copyrighted book accessible online, what does halacha say about printing it? I'm worried about gezeila on the one hand, but perhaps since there is no loss to the owner it doesn't fall under this category". You can [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/127089/edit) your question if you'd like. I can't speak for all of the books on Hebrewbooks, but there are indeed thousands of books on there that are not under copyright.

Comment: @magicker72 Do you know how to figure out if an individual Sefer is copyright, or is this beyond the scope of this site?

Comment: Probably beyond the scope, and probably highly dependent on the book (if it's published relatively recently). Also dependent on your local copyright laws.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Chaim and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Impossible to answer in general. Many Seforim writers want maximum publicity and reach for their Torah, and would be happy for others to print. Typically they don’t sell their works. There are even email lists that will send around new seforim of this type. Others are works being commercially sold and shouldn’t be printed. The copyright notice at the beginning of the book should guide you

Comment: The inner cover usually gives copyright information. Having found it on a random site doesn't really help, because you don't know whether the legal owner of the copyright had decided to share it for free. The expiration of copyright depends on the country of publication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain#Public_domain_books